# ¿Cómo saber si un item mostrado con append se repite, y si se repite solo cambiar la cantidad y no mostrarlo de nuevo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, condiciones

lo que pretendo lograr es que al enviar un código de un producto se verifique si ese código ya está siendo mostrado a través de un "append", y si ya se ha mostrado que no se muestre de nuevo si no que solo se modifique la cantidad. Yo creé una clase en un "hidden" que mostraba el código y comparé esa clase con el código que va llegando para determinar si es repetido, pero solo reconoce si es repetido el primer código que envió, de ahí en adelante si inserto nuevos códigos no los reconoce. Agradecería que me compartieran sus opiniones y conocimientos, de antemano muchísimas gracias.

Aquí esta mi código:

```
$("#buscarCodigo").change(function(){
  var codigo = $(this).val();
  if(codigo==$(".repetido").val(){
     alert("El codigo es repetido")    
   }
  var datos = new FormData();
  datos.append("codigo", codigo);
  $.ajax({
    url:"ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(respuesta){
      if (respuesta){
       var descripcion = respuesta["descripcion"];
      $(".nuevoArticulo").append(
    '<div class="row" style="padding:5px 15px">'+
   '<div class="col-sm" style="padding-right:0px">'+
          '<div class="input-group">'+
            '<span class="input-group-addon"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary retirarArticulo"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></span>'+
            '<input type="text" class="descripcion_articulo form-control" id="agregarArticulo" name="agregarArticulo" value="'+descripcion+'" required readonly>'+
            '<input type="hidden" class="form-control repetido" value="'+codigo+'">'+
           '</div>'+    
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="col-sm-2" >'+
          '<input type="number" class="form-control nuevaCantidadArticulo" name="nuevaCantidadArticulo" min="1" value="1" required>'+                
        '</div>'+
        '</div>')
      $("#buscarCodigo").val("");
      $("#buscarCodigo").focus();
      }else{
       alert("no hay registros")
        $("#buscarCodigo").val("");
        $("#buscarCodigo").focus();
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre hacer esto y me funciona muy bien, no estoy muy seguro si exista una mejor manera pero está me funciono le asigne al input de type hidden un id con el valor del codigo que envio y de esa forma identifico que input en especifico es el que esta repetido luego aplique algo similar a la cantidad pero con una clase que se llamara como el codigo para poder trabajar con esa clase especifica y cambiarla a medida que agrego productos y quedo algo asi :

```
    $("#buscarCodigo").change(function(){
      var codigo = $(this).val();
      if(codigo==$("#"+codigo).val(){
         $("."+codigo).val(Number($("."+codigo).val())+1);
       }else{
      var datos = new FormData();
      datos.append("codigo", codigo);
      $.ajax({
        url:"ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta){
          if (respuesta){
           var descripcion = respuesta["descripcion"];
          $(".nuevoArticulo").append(
        '<div class="row" style="padding:5px 15px">'+
       '<div class="col-sm" style="padding-right:0px">'+
              '<div class="input-group">'+
                '<span class="input-group-addon"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary retirarArticulo"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></span>'+
                '<input type="text" class="descripcion_articulo form-control" id="agregarArticulo" name="agregarArticulo" value="'+descripcion+'" required readonly>'+
                '<input type="hidden" class="form-control repetido" id="'+codigo+'" value="'+codigo+'">'+
               '</div>'+    
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-sm-2" >'+
              '<input type="number" class="'+codigo+' form-control nuevaCantidadArticulo" name="nuevaCantidadArticulo" min="1" value="1" required>'+                
            '</div>'+
            '</div>')
          $("#buscarCodigo").val("");
          $("#buscarCodigo").focus();
          }else{
           alert("no hay registros")
            $("#buscarCodigo").val("");
            $("#buscarCodigo").focus();
          }
        }
      })
     }
    })
```